# How to suppress Error: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

On my Databricks Community Edition the code `if len(crValue) is 0:` results with the error:

```
Error: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
```

Is it possible to suppress the error so as not to have the change the code to `if len(crValue) == 0:`?

Comment: That looks like Python. Why do you *not* want to use `==`?

Comment: Hi @lnSync thanks for reaching out. It's not that I don't want to use it. I was just wondering if there a way to suppress for now. As I'm in testing phase it would just be easier to at this that stage if I could just suppress it for now.

Comment: I have just downgraded my community edition to 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12) to see if that would just allow me to work with "is" but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you suppress it by replacing `is` with `==`. There is no legitimate reason to use `is` here.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow's scope is limited to _practical_, answerable questions. Do you have a _practical_ reason to want to use `is` (despite its semantics meaning that you're introducing the risk of incorrect results depending on whether or not an interned version of `0` is returned -- which Python doesn't guarantee either way)?

Comment: It is an implementation-dependent optimization that `len([]) is 0` can be true, not something the Python *language* guarantees will be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. `is` is for reference equality. It returns `True` when the two variables point to the same object (in memory). In your case, you need to check the value. That is why you need to use `==`.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is) for more information.